# Como procurar uma string num txt em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu queria que com este código conseguisse percorrer o meu arquivo txt e mostrasse todas a palavras iguais (que é a autonomia). Não sei se é possível e a única forma que eu consigo é fazer um  `print(pesquisar_registro(file,word))`  e assim só mostra a primeira palavra e não mostra mais nada.

```
file = 'aeronaves.txt'
word = input("Autonomia: ").lower()      
def pesquisar_registro( arq, txt ):
    nome = ""
    with open( arq, 'r' ) as a:
        for linha in a:
            linha = linha.strip('\n')
            if nome == "":
                if txt in linha.split():
                    nome = linha
                else:
                    registro = linha.split(',')
                    dic = { "Nome"   : registro[0],  \
                            "Autonomia"        : nome,         \
                            "Capacidade"  : registro[1]}
                    return dic;
    return None;
print (pesquisar_registro( file , word ))
```

o meu txt esta guardado desta forma:

```
123
boing747,123
123
boing567,567
345
boing456,567
```

Comment: Seu código esta repleto de erros, já tentou executar ele para vê o que acontece?

Comment: Eu já corrigi algumas indentações mal feitas mas sim funciona mas não quero só a primeira palavra igual eu queria todas as palavras iguais que aparecem no txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu código esta muito quebrado, você não conseguira muito com ele, aconselho até a tentar rescrever ele, mas se deseja o resultado usando o mesmo ou até mesmo vê como poderia fazer para que o seu código de certo fiz umas modificações, veja se corresponde.

```
file = 'diretorio/test.txt'
word = input("Autonomia: ").lower()


def pesquisar_registro(arq, txt):
    with open(arq) as a:
        for linha in a:
            linha = linha.strip('\n')
            if ',' not in linha:
                nome = linha
            elif ',' in linha and (txt in linha or txt in nome):
                registro = linha.split(',')
                dic = {"Nome": registro[0],
                       "Autonomia": nome,
                       "Capacidade": registro[1]}
                yield dic
    return None


for p in pesquisar_registro(file, word):
    print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode dividir seu problema em duas partes. A primeira parte seria responsável por carregar o conteúdo do arquivo integralmente para a memória, montando uma lista de dicionários, veja só:

```
def carregar_arquivo(arq):
    ret = []
    dic = {}
    with open( arq, 'r' ) as a:
        for n, linha in enumerate(a):
            linha = linha.strip()
            if n % 2:
                dic['Nome'], dic['Capacidade'] = linha.split(',')
                ret.append(dic)
                dic = {}
            else:
                dic['Autonomia'] = linha
    return ret
```

Testando:

```
dados = carregar_arquivo('aeronaves.txt')
print(dados)
```

Saída:

```
[
    {'Autonomia': '123', 'Nome': 'boing747', 'Capacidade': '123'},
    {'Autonomia': '123', 'Nome': 'boing567', 'Capacidade': '567'},
    {'Autonomia': '345', 'Nome': 'boing456', 'Capacidade': '567'}
]
```

Agora que você possui o conteúdo do seu arquivo em memória, a pesquisa por uma ocorrência nesta lista de dicionários ficaria bem simples:

```
def pesquisar( arquivo, txt ):
    ret = []
    dados = carregar_arquivo(arquivo)
    for i in dados:
        if any(txt in v for k, v in i.items()):
            ret.append(i)
    return ret
```

Testando:

```
ocorrencias = pesquisar('aeronaves.txt', 'boing747')
print(ocorrencias)
```

Saída:

```
[{'Autonomia': '123', 'Nome': 'boing747', 'Capacidade': '123'}]
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/PlayfulExperiencedWearables)